# What exactly is a "weight" in machine learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

I'm currently learning about perceptron learning algorithms in python and I came across the term "**weight**" when reading about Rosenblatt's [perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) rule. Can anyone explain to me exactly what this term means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of perceptron, **weight** stands for a "strength of the synaptic connection" (in interpretation) and for "parameter that you multiply by signal connected through given connection". It is also a common usecase to call the "connection" itself - a weight.

Thus in case of perceptron, your model is of form

```
perceptron(x) = sign( SUM_i w_i x_i )
                            ---      
                             |       
                           weight
```

Why is it called this way? Because you compute **weighted sum** of your features `x_i`, and corresponding `w_i` are **weights** of each features.

Comment: Thank you so much! That cleared it up. It makes so much sense now.